# How to get started with NNPack?

Tags: android, neon

My work has asked me to try out the NNPack math library (see it on Github at https://github.com/Maratyszcza) and report on its suitability for our Android project.  I've found no documentation either on Github or in the source code, and functions such as matrix multiplication involve so many unexplained parameters that it's difficult to impossible to perform even the simplest operation.

A Google search hints that NNPack is in use by many people.  Is this in fact  right, and if so, how did they learn how to use it?

Comment: Did you get this working? Details would help :)

Comment: No, I didn't and I don't have a resolution because I was asigned to a different project and left this question open.